# How to store videos for password protected site privately?

Tags: security, web

I'm making a site to display some videos of mine to a select few people. It's a password protected site that will only work if you have the correct cookie stored in your browser. If I simply put the videos in a directory, people who know to look for the files will be able to guess the url. How can I prevent this?

Comment: What webserver are you using

Comment: What backend technologies are you using? That changes the answer considerably.

Comment: I'm using a node server. Preferably using the Meteor framework

Answer (score 0):

There is no fool-proof way to do this. If the video is sent to their computer, they can copy it. You can make it more inconvenient however.

1. Stream the video instead of offering it for download
2. Add some user-specific info in the video URL, HMAC it, and check its validity when starting the stream

For example:

video url: http://example.com/streams/99?username=alice&ip=6.6.6.6&validUntil=1439167206&hmac=fe1373c0150a5053f8cdb135317ee889a9699d06

Where `validUntil` is probably only a few seconds in the future. Long enough for the browser to parse the response and connect to your streaming server.

Then on your streaming server, make sure user is logged in as `alice`, that her IP is `6.6.6.6` and that the current UTC timestamp is before `validUntil`, and then check that these values haven't been tampered with the HMAC.

AWS supports this kind of thing with [Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialStreamingJWPlayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

In a nut shell, you don't make the files accessible by the webserver directly.

Instead, the files will be accessed by the backend application behind your webserver that authenticates your users by cookie. The app will see who is trying to access the file and decide whether or not to let it out. Note that the app will need to be able to handle [byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) and/or media streaming.

In regards to guessing the url — just make it unguessable: use random / hash names. This will prevent authenticated users who were given url to a file from guessing urls to other files. Non-authenticated users will just not be able to access anything even if the url is known to them.

Comment: Will search engines be able to scrape the locations of these videos?

Comment: No unless you give them the password :)
Only authenticated and authorized clients will see the locations in the first place, whether humans or robots. If someone reveals a link to your video on another website, search engines still won't be successful in accessing it because they won't provide password.

Comment: But a path to an mp4 (http://domain.tld/14838383.mp4) cannot authenticate the cookie. Only an html page that displays the video can. What stops a person from checking the src of the video?

Comment: Whether a path can or cannot authenticate cookies depends on the webserver configuration, specifically whether it handles the path by itself or passes to the backend application. You can configure the webserver so that paths like `domain.tld/2983729.mp4` are handled by the app which will authenticate the cookie.